# How to append a UIImage or CGImage to an AVAssetWriter?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Is it possible to convert a UIImage instance to a CMSampleBufferRef so that it can be appended to a specified output file using AVAssetWriter's appendSampleBuffer: method?

If so ... how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't really tried this one possibility is to create a `CVPixelBuffer` using [CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/Reference/reference.html), and pointing it to the [raw pixels from the UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more).

Once this is done, since `CVPixelBuffers` are just `CVImageBuffers` you can use `CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer` to get a `CMSampleBufferRef` that you can then use the appendSampleBuffer method.

As I said previously I haven't ever tried this, but it looks plausible.

Comment: This looks good, but I got stuck on the `appendSampleBuffer:` call, see my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751664.