# what is the relation between CVBuffer and CVImageBuffer

Tags: ios, core-video

if you check this doc from apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVBufferRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CVBufferRef

In the very second line , it says that : "A CVBuffer object can hold video, audio, or possibly some other type of data. You can use the CVBuffer programming interface on any Core Video buffer." This means that it can hold images as well . If yes , then why do we have CVImageBuffer.

I have just done some work on generating images from a video using AVAssetImageGenerator.Now I want to merge frames to make a video.SO,I have just started reading about this.

My current status:
1.Well right now I know that I need to use AVAssetWriter.
2.Then I need to provide it an input using AVAssetWriterInput.
3.I need to use some CV and CG classes.

So please help me know the reason for using CVImageBuffer if we have CVBuffer.I know that CVBuffer is abstract but then CVImageBuffer doesn't inherit from CVBuffer.This bamboozles me even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CVImageBuffer` *does* inherit from `CVBuffer`, but only in that "simulated object orientation in c" way. That is, if you know that a `CVBuffer`'s type is that of a certain subclass, then you can safely cast to that type, e.g.:

```
if (CFGetTypeID(myCVBuffer) == CVMetalTextureGetTypeID()) {
    CVMetalTextureRef metalBuffer = myCVBuffer;
    // do something with metalBuffer
}
```

In fact you don't even need to cast (not even in swift!), as the `CVBuffer` types are all the same (`typealias`es in swift):

```
typedef CVBufferRef CVImageBufferRef;
typedef CVImageBufferRef CVPixelBufferRef;
typedef CVImageBufferRef CVMetalTextureRef;
// ...
```

You noticed that `CVBuffer` is an abstract base class, but you may have missed that is `CVImageBuffer` is abstract too: it adds a few functions involving image dimensions and colour spaces and defines image attachment keys for access to image specific metadata.

I assume your images are `CGImage`s since you're using an `AVAssetImageGenerator`. At this point you have two choices. You can convert the `CGImage` -> `CVPixelBuffer` and append that directly to a `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` that you add to your `AVAssetWriterInput`. Or you can create a `CMSampleBuffer` from the `CVPixelBuffer` created above using `CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer` and append that directly to your `AVAssetWriterInput`.

[Some people prefer the pixel buffer adaptor approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758152/22147), but honestly, both of the above approaches are daunting *and* inefficient (e.g. I don't think you can create the `CVPixelBuffer` without copying the `CGImage` pixels), so why not dump the `AVAssetImageGenerator` and its unwelcome `CGImage`s and use an `AVAssetReader` + `AVAssetReaderOutput` directly? It will vend `CMSampleBuffer`s that you can append without conversion* to your writer input and you will have a better chance of not hating your life.

<sub>* actually you may need to change the sample buffer's presentation time stamp, still pretty easy:</sub> `CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming`

Comment: Thanks but what does this "simulated object orientation in c" way mean?can you please elaborate?

Comment: CoreVideo is a C API and C doesn't have inheritance as a language feature. However you can simulate it, with caveats (proof/interesting fact: c++, which does have inheritance, used to compile to C - until exceptions made folks give up). Here is an example of one way you might got about simulating inheritance in C: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108830/Inheritance-and-Polymorphism-in-C

Comment: Does that answer your question?